# Multiple rows in subquery

Tags: postgresql, postgis, mapserver

I am trying to create a context of exclusion zone in my layer.

I am trying the following Map File/SQL combo

```
DATA "geom FROM public.data"
FILTER "layer = %layer_id% AND ST_CONTAINS(ALL(SELECT the_geom FROM public.exclusion_zone WHERE layer = %layer_id%), geom) != true"
```

Obviously this breaks when there are more then 1 exclusion zone, so how do I do this?

I've tried storedProc's already only to be told MapServer can't find it's SRID as it doesn't appear in the geometry table

The error I am receiving is thus

```
Query error. Error (ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression ) executing query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DATA "geom FROM public.data"
FILTER "
    layer = %layer_id% and
    not exists
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM public.exclusion_zone
        WHERE layer = %layer_id% and ST_CONTAINS(the_geom, geom)
    )
```

Comment: this looks like it should work, but im getting a SYNTAX ERROR near the "ANY" keyword?

Comment: Sorry about the delay, only just back from a trip - new SQL worked like a gem, thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a MapServer related question than a PostgreSQL/PostGIS one.
What version of MapServer are you using?

It's prefereable to avoid the `FILTER` parameter and use a subquery to retrieve your data from postgis explicitly providing the SRID and unique id field: you get better performance, more control, less headaches caused by MapServer and PostgreSQL query optimizer "missunderstandings".

I have no idea about your actual data, but pasting your lines togheter and assuming there is a `gid` field in the `public.data` table, you should get something like that:

```
DATA "geom from (
        SELECT gid, geom 
            FROM public.data 
            WHERE layer = %layer_id% AND ST_CONTAINS(ALL(SELECT the_geom FROM public.exclusion_zone WHERE layer = %layer_id%), geom) != true 
    ) as layer using unique gid using srid = %layer_id%"
```

Of course change the `%srid%` according to your data, or use -1. Depending on your PostGIS and MapServer version you could even avoid it (ok, it depends strictly on your data and query too), letting MapServer to get it for you, but it's an useless overhead.

About your query, it gives me the feeling something could be optimized in there, but I guess this is just a test query to be replaced with the final one.

Comment: interesting, i read the exact opposite about the filter parameter

Comment: the question is more postgis as I still get the error that the subquery returns more than one row (which is correct, ill update the original question with the exact error message)

Comment: About the `FILTER` parameter, I don't know what documentation you are reading, but probably you are mixing the information about file based data with spatial databases. The best way is to try yourself and check which is the best option anyways. About the error: your query IS wrong (Roman Pekar gave you a correct option, just add a `NOT`), but you wrote: *only to be told MapServer can't find it's SRID as it doesn't appear in the geometry table*. Test your queries outside MapServer before, when you are sure they give you the correct result set, then use them in your MapServer application.